# My wifi adapter is not working properly with ubuntu 20.4.3

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I have two problems about my wifi adapter on nmy laptop.

- ubuntu 20.4.3
- Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)

1. When I turn off wifi or open airplane mode I can not turn wifi back on. It doesn't recognise the adapter. When I tuırn off and on again it works.
2. Sometimes wifi conneciton is suddenly lost. I am next to modem signal power is good. It wont connect another network and journal logs looks like this: ( When I tuırn off and on again it works.)

```
 23:29:36 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
 23:29:36 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
 23:29:36 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
 23:29:21 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
 23:29:21 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
 23:29:21 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
 23:29:06 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
 23:29:06 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
 23:29:06 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
 23:28:51 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
 23:28:51 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
 23:28:51 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
 23:28:36 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
 23:28:36 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
 23:28:36 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
 23:28:21 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
```

I am not sure but it looks like i am facing "issue 2" when I use a browser vpn extension (cyberghost on firefox and opera). Maybe this can give a clue about it. I don't know.

Edit: Here is some more log

```
00:04:42 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
00:04:26 systemd-resolve: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
00:04:24 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
00:03:49 systemd-resolve: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
00:03:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:59:27 systemd-resolve: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
21 Eki 23:59:24 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:58:49 systemd-resolve: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
21 Eki 23:58:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:54:30 systemd-resolve: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
21 Eki 23:54:30 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:54:24 systemd-resolve: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
21 Eki 23:54:24 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:52:25 systemd-resolve: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
21 Eki 23:52:25 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
21 Eki 23:51:19 systemd-resolve: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
21 Eki 23:51:18 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:49 systemd-resolve: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
21 Eki 23:50:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:30 systemd-resolve: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
21 Eki 23:50:30 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:30 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:30 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:30 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
21 Eki 23:50:30 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:30 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:30 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:30 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:27 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
21 Eki 23:50:27 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:27 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:24 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:24 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:24 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:24 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
21 Eki 23:50:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:23 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:21 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
21 Eki 23:50:21 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:21 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:19 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
21 Eki 23:50:19 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:19 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:18 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:18 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:18 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:18 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:17 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
21 Eki 23:50:17 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:17 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
21 Eki 23:50:14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:14 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:12 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:12 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:12 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:12 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:10 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
21 Eki 23:50:10 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:10 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:08 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
21 Eki 23:50:08 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:08 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:07 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:07 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:07 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:07 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:50:07 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_ABORT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
21 Eki 23:50:07 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
21 Eki 23:49:59 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: regular scan timed out
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Queue 11 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [254, 4] HW [90, 90] FH TRB=0x05a5a5a5a
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00010000 00060011 000030c1 00002000 00000000 00000000
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi root port (0000:00:1c.6) AER cap structure:
.
.lots of numbers
.
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.6) config registers:
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: 0000000f df100460 00000000
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00003040 00002000 00000014 40000001
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
.
. Lots of numbers
.
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: 31658086 00100000 02800081 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
21 Eki 23:49:48 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
```

Comment: Did you install the drivers as described [here](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-install-intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-3165-drivers/) ?

Comment: Didn't work. My wifi adapter is working actually . But it dissappers out of nowhere. I added more logs if it makes sense.

Comment: I had a similar case once: wifi lost connecttion to my AP. Tried another one (like wifi hotspot on the phone) and it worked without problems. You might try this to localize the problem...

Comment: The thig is I was using same AP with same laptop before installing ubuntu. I was using it with windows and never had problem. I am thinking to get the conection with a cable :(

Answer (score 0):

Your data suggests that you need to install another driver for the WiFi to work.

In case you have those files:

```
iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode and iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
```

rename them to:

```
iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode and iwlwifi-3165-13.ucode
```

Reboot afterwards

An elaborate explanation can be found [here](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-install-intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-3165-drivers/)